# Excel extract value appearing after searched string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got an Excel spreadsheet with columns containing product attributes formatted this way:

`ca_colour=WHITE,ca_min_order_qty=4,ca_season=SS17,ca_sentiment=Inspiration,ca_type=Candles`

I've got hundreds of products for which I need to extract e.g. value of `ca_season` and I'm really struggling with figuring this one out. Different products might have `ca_season` in a different place of this cell.

I would appreciate any help with writing a formula for this search. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, if one has Excel 365, try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=LET(X,FIND("ca_season=",A1)+10,MID(A1,X,FIND(",",A1&",",X)-X))
```

---

More generic:

[image]

```
=LET(X,FIND(C1,A1)+LEN(C1)+1,MID(A1,X,FIND(",",A1&",",X)-X))
```

Answer (score 1):

`FILTERXML` will give desired result. Try-

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(., 'ca_season')]")
```

[image]

If you are not using Excel365 then user `FILTERXML()` with `INDEX()` function.

```
=INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(., 'ca_season')]"),1)
```

As @JvdV mentioned in comment you may want only product code then use like-

```
=REPLACE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(.,'ca_season=')]"),1,10,"")
```

And a fantastic [tips & tricks on FilterXML()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml) here from JvdV

Comment: Nice, beaten me to it haha. You might want to use: `=REPLACE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(.,'ca_season=')]"),1,10,"")`. Though, you don't need to use `INDEX()` in previous versions of Excel due to implicit intersection.

Comment: Thanks, both of you that's very helpful. I wish I could say I understand anything of these formulas. Have a great day!

Comment: Sorry, one more question is there any way of making this formula more generic let's say can I put e.g ca_colour in a different cell and use this cell's reference instead of typing ca_colour into a formula? 
@JvdV same with your formula can I make it more generic to only retrieve what's after the "=" or do I have to adjust number of characters every time I need to extract a different value. 
Thanks for your patience guys.

Comment: @Lukasz Ask that as a separate question.